# "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare" when reusing xml parsing code

Tags: php, xml

I have a single xml parsing function that I'm trying to call multiple times as I only need to strip a little data out and continue on.

Here is the function:

```
//Parse Product ID from Product Sides
function getProductSpecs($xml,$type) {

    // Setup arrary
    global $productspecs;
    global $count;
    $count = 0;
    global $type_check;
    $type_check = $type;

    // Parse the XML
    // Create the parser
    if (! ($xmlparser = xml_parser_create()) )
    { 
     die ("Cannot create name list parser");
    }

    // Start tag function
    function first($parser, $name, $attribs) {
        global $trigger;
        if ($name == "PRODUCTSIDEID") {
            $trigger = 1;
        } elseif ($name == "PRODUCTID") {
            $trigger = 1;
        }
    }

    // data handler function
    function xml($parser, $data) {
        global $trigger;
        global $productspecs;
        global $count;
        global $type_check;
        if ($trigger == 1){
            if ($type_check == "sideid") {
                $productspecs[$count]=$data;
                $count = $count + 1;
            } elseif ($type_check == "productid") {
                $productspecs[$count]=$data;
                $count = $count + 1;
            }               
            $trigger = 0;
        }
    }

    // Call the handler functions
    xml_set_element_handler($xmlparser, "first", "");

    // Call the data handler
    xml_set_character_data_handler($xmlparser, "xml");

    // Parse the XML data
    xml_parse($xmlparser,$xml);
    // Clear parser
    xml_parser_free($xmlparser);

    //Return the array
    return $productspecs;
}
```

My problem arises when this is called:

```
xml_set_element_handler($xmlparser, "first", "");
```

I get the redeclare error on:

```
function first($parser, $name, $attribs) {
```

The function only appears the one time and I'm assuming the problem occurs on the call but is there a way around this so I don't have to duplicate so much code. I'm going to have to iterate through this multiple times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining functions inside of functions can lead to this.  Each time you run `getProductSpecs()` it's going to try to declare `first()` and `xml()` again, and in PHP, all user functions are [declared in a global scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).  The best solution is to move your `first()` function and your `xml()` function outside of the main `getProductSpecs()` function.

Another option is to use [function_exists()](http://php.net/function_exists) around your function declarations, like this:

```
if (! function_exists('first')) {
 // Start tag function
    function first($parser, $name, $attribs) {
        global $trigger;
        if ($name == "PRODUCTSIDEID") {
                $trigger = 1;
        } elseif ($name == "PRODUCTID") {
                $trigger = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I figured it was something to that effect I just hadn't wrapped my head around it.